# Поиск в таблице с частичным индексом

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Если на таблицу создан частичный индекс (например только на ID поля, где значение другого поля deleted = false), то будет ли производится поиск по оставшейся части таблицы, при ненахождении данных в индексе?
То есть какая-то запись не нашлась в этом частичном индексе, после этого поиск прекращается или будет произведен дополнительный поиск по неиндексированным данным?

например:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name
ON my_table_name(id)
WHERE deleted > 0;
```

и потом

```
SELECT * FROM my_table_name
 WHERE id = 5
 AND deleted >= 0;
```

Comment: *Если на таблицу создан частичный индекс (например только на ID поля, где значение другого поля deleted = false)* Укажите точно СУБД и приведите пример CREATE TABLE такой таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

Такой индекс вовсе не будет использоваться для такого запроса.

Частичный индекс может использоваться только если в запросе указано условие поиска, подходящее под предикат этого частичного индекса.

То есть, [например](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html),

```
CREATE INDEX orders_unbilled_index ON orders (order_nr)
WHERE billed is not true;
```

Может использоваться в запросе `WHERE billed is not true AND order_nr < 10000;`. Но не может для условия

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_nr = 3501;
```

Т.к. неизвестно, какое значение billed может быть у этого order_nr.